Can VS Code display a Markdown syntax preview?
I am typing a README document in Markdown using Visual Studio Code. I found an online browser-based tool called Markdown Live Preview, but I was wondering if VS Code had any sort of handy split-window preview pane already built into it.

CTRL+SHIFT+V...

Right Click on MarkDown file, choose Markdown Preview Enhanced: Open Preview to the Side  Ctrl-K V . ~Enjoy~

Read the fine manual: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/markdown

You can click on the Open preview to the slide button available at top right or press Ctrl+K V


